# Python splitting text file by x amount of lines for x amount of sections

Tags: python

Ok So I am trying to create a script that will allow me to open up an already existing text file and split x amount of grouped lines for x amount of turns

I have managed to create a small working example, however it is not easily expandable as you can see I have created a variable for each line within each group.

and its not a very realistic approach if I am dealing with a text file that has 1000's of lines that lets say I want to extract 7 groups of 327 lines.

Script.

```
batch_amount = 5

group_amount = 10

file = open("animals", 'r')
lines = file.read()
words = lines.splitlines()

n = 0
while n < group_amount:

  one = words[n]
  two = words[n+1]
  three = words[n+2]
  four = words[n+3]
  five = words[n+4]

  final = one +'\n'+ two +'\n'+ three +'\n'+ four +'\n'+ five

  animal_group = open("animal_group" + str(n), 'w')
  animal_group.write(final)
  n+=1
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you could try to do it like this:

```
batch_amount = 5

group_amount = 10

file = open("animals", 'r')
lines = file.read()
words = lines.splitlines()

n = 0
while n < group_amount:
  final = ''
  for i in range(batch_amount):
        final += words[n + i] + '\n'

  animal_group = open("animal_group" + str(n), 'w')
  animal_group.write(final)
  n+=1
```